# Ajax post request of form data to node/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

thanks in advance for reading.
I am trying to get a simple example working of posting data to a node/express server.  The post executes from the ajax code and express see the request and I can get a response back from express into the ajax code.  So the path works.  What I can't figure out is how to pass the data in the post request and parse in express.

on the express side I have a log statement:

```
   console.log("Body: " + req);
```

and it just shows me:

```
   Body: [object Object]
```

So, I am either not setting the data up properly in the post request or I am not trying to decode it properly.

That is one problem.  The other problem I have is that when I do the post I am also seeing a GET request in express.

I have searched and searched dozens, if not hundreds, of posts and just can't figure out what is going on.  At this point, I am kind of all tied up and have changed so many things I don't know if I am even close any longer.

To make it easier (maybe) I am just trying to hard code some data in the ajax code and not use the data from the actual form.

```
    <form id="productKeyForm">
        <div id="keyInput">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="number" id="productKey" name="productKey" />
                <button id="getPrdKey">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $("#getPrdKey").click(function () {
            console.log("ajax submit form entered, key: " + jQuery("#productKey").val());
            var data = {};
            data.title = "title";
            data.msg = "msg";
            $.ajax({
                url: "/submit-form",
                type: "POST",
                //                contentType: 'application/json',
                //                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("succes returned in ajax");
                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    console.log("post resulted in failure");
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

And the express side:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();    
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.method + " request for " + req.url);
    next();
    });

app.use(express.static("./"));  // filesystem???

app.post("/submit-form", function (req, res) {
    console.log("Body: " + req);
    res.send("9999");
});
app.listen(80);
```

The following is `console.log` that I see when I run and enter 12345 in the form field:

```
Listen on port 80

GET request for /

GET request for /css/styles.css

POST request for /submit-form

Body: [object Object]

GET request for /?productKey=12345

GET request for /css/styles.css
```

So, even though my "post" is just using hard-coded data and not the form data, I still get a "GET" request with the form data that I entered.  And the post data just shows up as [object Object].

Just realized I am asking two questions in this post.  One about the post data and one about the additional "GET" that I wasn't expecting.  Should this be asked as two different questions?

Comment: I think if you change `console.log("Body: " + req)` to `console.log(req)` you will get to see what request actually is and not that [object Object] string.

Comment: that is true.  I change the log statement and get hundreds of lines of output.  Nothing I see in the output helps me decipher what might be happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `[Object object]` is the result of `Object.toString()` method on your `req` object because you've concatenated it with a string here: `console.log("Body: " + req)`:

Whether stringify an object to print it :

```
console.log( "Body: " + JSON.stringify(req, null, 2) );
```

or simply use a comma ( console will evaluate values and separate em with `space`:

```
console.log("Body: ", req );
```

`req.body` is the body of your `POST` request:

```
 console.log("Body: ", req.body );
```

2. You've got an extra `GET` request because this is the default behaviour of **browsers** to submit a form when `submit` button got clicked. If you want to handle form submission by yourself ( which here you've done ) you first should prevent the form from submitting then customize it:

   ```
   $("#getPrdKey").click(function (e) {
     // prevent form submission
     e.preventDefault();
     // custom submit
     console.log("ajax submit form entered, key: " + jQuery("#productKey").val());
     var data = {};
     ...
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the tip on "preventDefault".  That resolved the issue regarding the unexpected "GET".

Comment: regarding the logging of the data, when I use your suggestion of:

Comment: Sorry, bad comment...  When I use your suggestion of console.log( "Body: " + JSON.stringify(req, null, 2) ); I get an stack dump that indicates :TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".

Comment: so don't need to stringify, just use comma syntax. and to print the body of your post request get the body part of it: `console.log('Body: ', req.body)`

Comment: If I simple do the following:      console.log(req.body);    I get output of   {}

Comment: I think you need to uncomment: `content-type: application/json`

Comment: ding, ding, ding, we have a winner.  I thought I was close, thank you for helping me get this going.

Comment: did someone "down vote" your answer?  Not sure why, it helped me solve my problem.  Thanks again.